# Where to place nginx.conf file in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a flask app running in AWS ec2 inside a docker container and I am having latency problems. I figured this is because inside the container, localhost routes to both ipv4's `127.0.0.1` and ipv6's `::1` (based on some other SO posts). I found [this blog post](https://blog.jverkamp.com/2015/04/03/performance-problems-with-flask-and-docker/) which addresses the issue exactly. But in the blog he uses nginx, which I've never used before. He has an nginx config file:

```
location / { try_files $uri @project; }
location @project {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

and I'm not sure how I can place this in the container so that it reads properly. I read somewhere that it goes in /etc/nginx, but then how do I edit the dockerfile to include this conf there?

This is the Dockerfile he suggests. Is the line `ADD nginx /etc/nginx` where the file is getting copied in? and he just didn't give the file an extension?

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential nginx python3.4 python3.4-dev
RUN easy_install3 pip

WORKDIR /project

ADD requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /project

ADD nginx /etc/nginx

CMD uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w project:app --chown-socket=www-data:www-data --enable-threads & \
    nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, he is adding the file `nginx` to the container file system location `/etc/nginx/`

Personally I'd name the file `nginx.conf` as that is the default name according to the `nginx` documentation.

> By default, the configuration file is named nginx.conf and placed in
>   the directory /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx, or
>   /usr/local/etc/nginx.

Also, I'd recommend using `COPY` in stead of `ADD` according to the [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)

> For other items (files, directories) that do not require ADD’s tar
>   auto-extraction capability, you should always use COPY.

To make this work you'll need to install `nginx` on the container you're running flask on.